# I made a Python 'robber's language' translating programme, is it correct?

Tags: python

so i'm just a noob in python and i was doing this exercise:

> "Write a function translate() that will translate a text into "rövarspråket" (Swedish for "robber's language"). That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon"."

I was able to do it here is my code :

```
def translate (var1):
    vaw = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']
    var1 = list(var1)
    for string  in var1:
        if string == string in vaw:
           var1[var1.index(string)] = string + 'o' + string
    print ''.join(var1)
```

I was wondering if this is correct or if there's another way to do it with less code?

Comment: Even if you fix the indentation error, your code doesn't work. `string == string in vaw` is equivalent to `True in vaw`, which is never true.

Answer (score 9):

```
def translate(s):
  consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
  return ''.join(l + 'o' + l if l in consonants else l for l in s)

print(translate("this is fun"))
```

Comment: +1, for the sheer simplicity and elegance of the solution

Comment: slower than a regex though (I think) ... but +1 all the same for readablity

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Do you really care if it's slower? And, if you _do_, why would you assume without testing? For this tiny string, according to `%timeit`, this version takes 4.72us vs. 28.1us for the regex (and that's even counting the cost of the extra function call against this one). And taking a 128K HTML document, `%timeit` says this one is 28.3ms vs. 125ms for the `re`. So, it's 5x faster than a regex.

Answer (score 5):

regex is a good solution

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub(r"([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])",r"\1o\1","this is fun")
tothohisos isos fofunon
```

Comment: Nice - I wouldn't have thought about that one

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to do this:

```
vaw = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']
```

… to get a sequence of characters. A string is already a sequence of characters. (The same is true for `var1`, but there, your code is requiring a *mutable* sequence of characters, where you can replace any character with a longer string, so you *do* need a `list`.)

Also, your code doesn't actually work, because `string == string in vaw` is the same as `True in vaw`, which is always false. I think you meant `if string in vaw`. While we're at it, I wouldn't call a variable `string`, because that's the name of a built-in module.

And you can save a few keystrokes by not adding extra whitespace in places where standard Python style (PEP8) says not to. :)

So:

```
def translate(var1):
    vaw = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    var1 = list(var1)
    for s in var1:
        if s in vaw:
           var1[var1.index(s)] = s + 'o' + s
    print ''.join(var1)
```

Next, if you want the index of each element in `var1`, you don't want to throw it away, and then find it again with `index`. Besides being more code and slower, it's also going to give you the wrong answer for any element that appears more than once. So:

```
def translate(var1):
    vaw = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    var1 = list(var1)
    for i, s in enumerate(var1):
        if s in vaw:
           var1[i] = s + 'o' + s
    print ''.join(var1)
```

This is about as far as you can go if you want to mutate the `var` list in-place. You could change it to do `var1[i+1:i+1] = 'o' + s`, to insert the new elements after the existing one, but then you have to iterate over a copy of `var1` (you can't change the shape of anything while iterating over it), and you have to keep track of how your indexes shifted, and so on.

It's usually a lot simpler to just build a new structure than to modify the old one in place. That's what list comprehensions, generator expressions, `map`, `filter`, etc. are there for. For each element `s` of the original list, you want `s + 'o' + s` if it's in `vaw`, just `s` otherwise, right? You can translate that right into Python:

```
def translate (var1):
    vaw = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    new_var1 = (s + 'o' + s if s in vaw else s for s in var1)
    return ''.join(new_var1)
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Of course by the time I got done explaining, NPE had already written very nearly the exact same answer 4 minutes ahead of me. :)