# Robbers language - translating back?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the python robbers language question mentioned here:

[I made a Python 'robber's language' translating programme, is there another way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396739/i-made-a-python-robbers-language-translating-programme-is-there-another-way)

Is great - and i am currently enjoying the regex solution - is there a similar regex solution to put the robbers language BACK in to it's original word?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write one yourself? What happened?

Comment: No not really - Basically any consonant, lets use L as an example would change to LOL and y would change to yoy

Comment: Try making it yourself? Also, please include some source code in this question... it would make things easier for yourself as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use regex substitution with a pattern where a consonant is followed by `o` and by itself:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])o\1', r'\1', 'tothohisos isos fofunon')
```

*Output*

```
this is fun
```

Comment: Why the outer grouping at all? You can remove a capturing group and refer to `\1` instead.

Comment: Actually for no reason :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anything with a repeated consonant around an `o` is replaced with the consonant itself:

```
re.sub(r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])o\1', r'\1', inputtext)
```

The `[....]` is a character group, matching one character that is part of the set. This character is captured in a capturing group (the `(...)` parentheses). Next a literal `o` must match. The `\1` is a back-reference, meaning that the exact same text as the first capturing group must match. Thus, it only matches character sequences like `tot` or `zoz`.

We then reuse the same capturing group to define the replacement; each match of 3 characters is replaced by the first character.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = "tothohisos isos fofunon"
>>> re.sub(r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])o\1', r'\1', inputtext)
'this is fun'
```