# What is this piece of code doing, python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am self learning python and I was doing an exercise, the solution to which was posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396739/i-made-a-python-robbers-language-translating-programme-is-it-correct) thread. Could anyone translate into english what this piece of code means? When I learned if statements I never came across this syntax.

```
 consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
 return ''.join(l + 'o' + l if l in consonants else l for l in s)
```

Comment: This basically takes every character in ``s`` and inserts an ``o`` in-between ``s`` and ``s``. e.g: ``cat`` -> ``cocatot`` (*excluding vowels*)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a longer piece of code, written as a generator. Here is what it would look like, more drawn out.

```
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'

ls = []
for l in s:
    if l in consonants:
        ls.append(l + 'o' + l)
    else:
        ls.append(l)

return ''.join(ls)
```

It loops through `s` and checks if `l` is in the string `consonants`. If it is, it pushes `l + 'o' + l` to the list, and if not, it simply pushes `l`.

The result is then joined into a string, using `''.join`, and returned.

More accurately (as a generator):

```
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'

def gencons(s):
    for l in s:
        if l in consonants:
            yield l + 'o' + l
        else:
            yield l

return ''.join(gencons(s))
```

Where `gencons` is just a arbitrary name I gave the generator function.

Comment: An important difference is that it doesn't actually create or use a list. It just iterates through s and yields up those new values.

Comment: What is consonants? is it a function that tells you whether a letter is a consonant?

Comment: It's a string from your post. @Aeleon

Comment: ok so this still doesn't make sense. in the for loop, l is a temporary variable used to execute the loop, like i which is commonly used in c++. How would the program know whether the character it's looking at is a consonant or now? since nothing is supposed to happen to vowels. I just realized that this string is made entirely of consonants but what if it wasn't? In c++, I would have a different function which would check whether the current character is a consonant or not and then use the if statements. Does python have a way to make this simpler or do I solve the problem the same as in c++

Comment: If the character is in the `consonants` string, it is a consonant. This is because `consonants` *is a string of all English consonants*. In Python, you don't need a separate function, you can simply use the `in` operator. For example, `'a' in 'abc'` will return `True`, while `1 in [5, 6, 7]` will return `False`. @Aeleon

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code contains neither an `if` statement nor a `for` loop. You can tell most easily because statements cannot be embedded in an expression, such as the one being passed as the argument to `join`.

```
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
return ''.join(l + 'o' + l if l in consonants else l for l in s)
```

The `if` is part of a *conditional expression*, which has the form `x if y else z`. Unlike an `if` statement, the `else` is mandatory, because the expression must have a value whether or not `y` is true. If `y` is true, the value is `x`; otherwise, the value is `z`. In this case, the value is either `l + 'o' + l` (when `l` is a consonant) or `l` itself.

The `for` keyword is used to indicate a *generator expression*, which you can think of as essentially as a way to generate a sequence of values based on another sequence. Here, we start with the some sequence `s`, and produce another value for each of the characters `l` in that sequence. The resulting sequence is used by `join` to produce a new string.

(Slightly off-topic, but it's more efficient to explicitly pass a list, not a generator, to `join`, since it needs to build a list first anyway to figure out how much space to allocate for the resulting string.

```
return ''.join([l + 'o' + l if l in consonants else l for l in s])
```

)

Comment: An `else` is not required in all forms of conditional expressions.

Comment: Please give an example of one that can omit the `else`.

Comment: Off the top of my head: `list(c for c in 'abc123' if c.isalpha())`. However, when used in a `lambda`, an `else` is required.

Comment: That's not a conditional expression; it's the `if` clause of a generator expression. They just both use the `if` keyword, but they are distinct parts of the grammar.